# TFS Adding files with MSBuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a number of files that are created during my MSBuild process which are held in an MSBuild directory.

What I need to be able to do is that these files and store then in a different location in TFS.  But how do I do this using MSBuild?

Answer (score 2):

The [**MSBuild Extension Pack**](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) has a nice set of tasks for interacting with TFS.
To check-in files from MSBuild, use the `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsSource`task:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsSource 
    TaskAction="Checkin" 
    ItemPath="C:\projects\SpeedCMMI\Demo1" 
    WorkingDirectory="C:\projects\SpeedCMMI" 
    Comments="Testing" 
    Notes="Code reviewer=buildrobot" 
    OverrideText="Justdoit" />
```

Comment: The working Directory seems to be being ignored when it is run in MSBuild. 

It is still trying to use the default working directory.